# How to Transform Columns/Rows in R based on variables in the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change up how my data frame looks based on variables in different columns. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Date          VH      Team
2016-10-25    V       NYK
2016-10-25    H       CLE
2016-10-25    V       GSW
2016-10-25    H       CHI
2016-10-26    V       UTA
2016-10-26    H       POR
```

I want to separate the VH and Team column into VisitorTeam and HomeTeam so my dataframe would look like this:

```
Date          VisitorTeam  HomeTeam
2016-10-25    NYK          CLE
2016-10-25    GSW          CHI
2016-10-26    UTA          POR
```

This code works to a degree:

```
reshape = reshape(transform(nbaodds, time = 
                              as.numeric(factor(VH))), 
                  idvar = "Date", dir = "wide")
```

Since the ID Var is date and it has two instances of "2016-10-25" it only takes in the first one and not the other game that happens on that day. So the output is only

```
Date          VisitorTeam  HomeTeam
2016-10-25    NYK          CLE
2016-10-26    UTA          POR
```

Anyone know how to fix this code or has a different code that would work to migrate the data to new columns?

Comment: The logical problem is, that you have no "match number": how do you know that on the 2016-10-25 NYK did play against CLE and not CHI? Both CLE and CHI are home teams on that day

Comment: That makes sense, is there a different way I could go about this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the order is right? meaning that each V and subsequent H have played against each other?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, was just using an example of my data in this question

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the order is 100% correct this would be a possible solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = ifelse(ID %% 2 == 0, ID - 1, ID)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = VH, values_from = Team)
```

I used the rownumber as ID and substracted 1 from every even number - this way you have identifier for matches that the tidyr::pivot_wider can pick up for separating the teams in home and away